# How to get an a tag hover to also work on wrapped span

Tags: html, css

I have a span tag that has a background image on it then inside it I have an a tag with text link. The span has the background image set to the right of the text link. I want when you rollover the a tag for it to also cover the span background image in its hover state also. 
I tried something like this but still not working.

```
        span a:first-child + span a:hover{
            cursor: pointer;
        }
```

Markup html

```
        <div class="wrapper">
            <span>Study Bill</span>
            <span><a href="#">Download PDF</a></span>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do it the other way; wrap your span with one big `<a>` tag, and write the link text inside the `<span>`. For instance:

```
<a href = "#">
    <span style = "background-image: url(your_image.png);">
        Download PDF
    </span>
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't change properties of parents in CSS upon interaction with children - it works one way only. However you can do something like this - http://jsfiddle.net/uH2XP/

```
<a href="#">some link text</a>

<style>
a:after {
    content: '';
    display: inline-block;
    height: 20px;
    width: 20px;
    background: green;
}

a:hover:after {
    background: orange;
}
</style>
```

Just replace `content: ''` with `content: url(path/to/your/image.png)`

Answer (score 0):

I would probably try to assign the background to the link and the span. Then you can have the hover state handle the background transition.

```
<style>
     div.wrapper a, div.wrapper span{background:#f00;}
     div.wrapper a:hover{background:#0f0;}
</style>

<div class="wrapper">
     <span>Study Bill</span>
     <a href="#">Download PDF</a>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/sdowswell/sz6fq/

Comment: Thats great but the text and the PDF image needs to be hover state?

Comment: Not sure where you're displaying your image, but you could set it as a non-repeating background element on your link element and add some padding to nudge the text over as needed... so you could add the following to your link/span style: background:url(pdfimage.png) no-repeat left; padding-left:20px;

This would also keep the image from diluting your content, and make image refresh easier down the line if needed.